# Nodejs auto logout session when I refresh website

Tags: node.js

I have small chat on my website.

```
var Session= Session({ secret:'secrettokenhere', saveUninitialized: true,resave: true});
```

When I refresh website, nodejs session auto logout. Could you help how do I fix ?

Comment: How are you saving the session in the browser? Somehow your browser has to tell your application that it has an active session. Are you using cookies or a JSON web token for example?

Comment: I have jus fund broken Socket after refresh